# Не отображается статья из БД при использовании $_GET

Tags: php, html

Может знает кто как решить проблему, когда нажимаю на статью с главной страницы пишет что статья не найдена, при этом если ещё дописать `echo print_r($article);` то выдаёт `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) 1`, если же убирать условие `(int)$_GET['id']`, то тогда он всё же находить статью с первым id. Как с этим разобраться я уже который день понять не могу. Вот сам кусок кода:

```
<?php
    $article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = ".(int)$_GET['id']);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($article) <= 0)
    {
?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="content__left col-md-8">
        <div class="block">
          <h3>Cтатья не найдена</h3>
          <div class="block__content">
            <div class="full-text">
              Запрашиваемая вами статья не существует
              <?php echo print_r($article);?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="content__right col-md-4">
        <?php include "includes/sidebar.php";?>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    } else {
        $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article);
        mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `articles` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id` = " . (int) $art['id']);
?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="content__left col-md-8">
        <div class="block">
          <a><?php echo $art['views']; ?> просмотров</a>
          <h3><?php echo $art['title']; ?></h3>
          <div class="block__content">
            <img src = "static/images/<?php echo $art['image']; ?>" style = "max-width: 100%;">
            <div class="full-text">
              <?php echo $art['text']; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Добавьте `echo mysql_error();` сразу после `$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = ".(int)$_GET['id']);` возможно это поможет найти ответ на вопрос

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, данное действие ничего не отображает, я просто только начал это изучать и пока не понял до конца как осуществляются данные запросы и какими способами находить ошибки

Comment: Знакомый код. Тоже сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с этой проблемой. подозреваю, что дело в том, что в index.php ошибка в написании ссылки на article.php